# Java's unsigned bitshift right (>>>) is signed shifting

Tags: java

I'm trying to bitshift right in order to isolate certain bits from a byte so I wanted an unsigned shift, the "new" bits should be zeros by my understanding. However, I've found that >>> has no difference to >> in my tests. -128 >> 4 = -8 as expected, but -128 >>> 4 should be 8 but I still get -8.

```
byte data = (byte)-128;
System.out.println((byte)(data >>> 4));
System.out.println((byte)(data >> 4));
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unsigned right-shift operator is indeed doing an unsigned right-shift in this code; it's just hidden because of implicit cast from `byte` to `int`. Says the Java Language Specification ([§15.19](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19)):

> The operators `<<` (left shift), `>>` (signed right shift), and `>>>` (unsigned right shift) are called the shift operators. The left-hand operand of a shift operator is the value to be shifted; the right-hand operand specifies the shift distance. [...] Unary numeric promotion (§5.6.1) is performed on each operand separately.

*Unary numeric promotion* means ([§5.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1)):

> [...] if the operand is of compile-time type `byte`, `short`, or `char`, it is promoted to a value of type `int` by a widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2).

So your code is evaluated as follows:

- The `byte` value `-128` which is the left operand of `>>>` is promoted to the `int` value `-128`, which is `0b11111111111111111111111110000000` in binary.
- The unsigned right-shift is done on this `int` value, with the result `268435448` which in binary is `0b00001111111111111111111111111000`. Note that the four left-most bits are zero, as you would expect from an unsigned right-shift.
- This result is then explicitly casted to `(byte)`, giving the result `-8`.

Using the REPL:

```java
> byte b = -128;
> int shifted = b >>> 4;
> shifted
268435448
> (byte) shifted
-8
```

For the behaviour you want, you can use `& 0xFF` to do an "unsigned" conversion from `byte` to `int`:

```java
> ((b & 0xFF) >>> 4)
8
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely understand now! It shifted it as an Int and casting to a byte truncated the remaining ones and the "new" zeros!

Answer (score 1):

The signed right shift operator '>>' uses the sign bit to fill the trailing positions and the unsigned right shift operator '>>' do not use the sign bit to fill the trailing positions. It always fills the trailing positions by 0s